# Unable to build android-support-v7

Tags: android, eclipse, android-support-library

I've downloaded the Android SDK.  I am trying to build the appcompat project.  I've read that project is located here:

`C:\Android\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat`

I have imported the project into my workspace.  It doesn't build.

I could go into great detail about which SDKs I have installed on my machine, etc.  I could say that the values-v11, values-v14, and values-v21 folders all have errors, even though I have downloaded all three of these SDKs.  But I am pretty sure if I import a project from the Android SDK website from the Android developer website, and I try to build that project, it should just work.  I've followed the instructions here:

https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#libs-with-res

...and still not working.

So, why does this not work?  I don't even care how to get it to work, I want to know why this does not work and why would I have to do any extra work or research to get it to build?  Is this a problem with Eclipse?  Should I be giving up on Eclipse and moving to Android Studio? This appears to be an incredibly simple thing to do and yet it does not work anymore.

Comment: Why don't you use jar file instead?

Comment: that's not working either. added the library, added to build path, all that good stuff.

Comment: i know that this is a rant, but in all seriousness if this is what we can expect for the future of eclipse support, then we need to know that.